# Get event when Xamarin.Forms View is ready

Tags: events, xamarin.forms, layout

For quite some time I was trying to find some kind of event or hook that notifies me when the view drawing is done.

E.g. I'm converting my controls to images for performance reasons, because they're complex and this way it's a lot faster. But I cannot really say when the drawing process is done so I'm just guessing with a time delay. Of course this is not really satisfying.

So does anyone see a solution to this problem? Is there a way to tell when the control is fully drawn? Or is this just not possible, but why then?

Comment: Not clear what is your problem, please provide detailed info about your problem, or some code provided.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT Replaced "building" by "drawing". I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: Any code that you have tried? Can you provide some code here?